# Unity: Unable to clear the TMPro text animated using DoTween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

I have a [TMPro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/beta-projects/textmesh-pro-84126) text object in Unity as shown below:
[image]

During the game level, I add texts which to this object which are animated using the DOText from [DOTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676), e.g. `pickUpTextObj.DOText(pickUptext, 2f, true).SetRelative(true);`

Once the levels is cleared and the new level is loaded, I need to clear this text field. I have tried all the three options as shown below in comment, but none of them is working. The text doesn't clear off and is stubborn. The text is attached to a `DontDestroyOnLoad` gameobject, and persists across levels.

```
pickUpTextObj = GameObject.Find("pickUpTexts").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
//pickUpTextObj.DOText("\n", 0f, true).SetRelative(false);
//pickUpTextObj.DOText("", 0f, true).SetRelative(false);
//pickUpTextObj.text = "";
```

Comment: have you tried `ClearSubMeshObjects` or `ClearMesh`?

Comment: No, I haven't. Let me try them and get back to you.

Comment: Not sure, what is happening. At the time when I posted this question it was not working fine. I went back to work on the game today after 5 days, and it is working as expected. I didn't change anything or updated my unity during this time.